# Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found - Hive R

Tags: r, linux, hadoop, hive

I am connected to a remote R server which is built on `x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)` platform. The R version installed in this server is `3.3.1`. I want to connect to remote hive database using this R server so that I can extract data and do some analysis on it. I am trying the following things,

```
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx8g" )
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)

drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
            "/home/username/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/hive-jdbc-0.10.0.jar",
            identifier.quote="`")
```

I am getting error as `Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found`. I downloaded the jar file and kept it in this path , `/home/username/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/`. I have downloaded only this jar file. Inside this `/home/username/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/` path, I am having three folders such as DBI, rJava and RJDBC and the file hive-jdbc-0.10.0.jar.

Apart from this have not downloaded anything else for now. Is there anything else which I need to download in order for this error to resolve?

Another attempt which I tried was,

```
hivedrv <- JDBC("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
                c(list.files("/home/username/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/",pattern="jar$",full.names=T),
                  list.files("/home/username/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/",pattern="jar$",full.names=T)))
```

which ran without any error. But when I try the following command,

```
hivecon <- dbConnect(hivedrv, "jdbc:hive://hostname:portname/", "username", "password")
```

I am getting the following error,

```
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/MetaException
```

Not sure how to solve this problem. Can anybody please help me in connecting the R server to Hive database? Any information would be helpful.

Comment: did you ever get this issue rectified?